# ¿Cómo puedo obtener el resultado de un número factorial en php?

Tags: php, revisión-de-código, matemáticas

Tengo un script en php con operaciones matemáticas, y una de ellas es obtener números factoriales. En la documentación oficial se hace uso de la función `gmp_fact()`  pero cuando intento usarla no me muestra nada (no da error): mi script es el siguiente:

```
<?php
            $a = $_POST['a'];
            $b = $_POST['b'];
            //Apartado 1
            if (is_numeric($a) && is_numeric($b)){
                echo "Las variables introducidas son números </br>";
            }
            else {
                die("No has introducido números");

            }
            //Apartado 2
            echo "A es $a y B es $b </br>";
            //Apartado 3
            $suma = $a + $b;
            echo "La suma es $suma </br>";
            //apartado 4
            $producto = $a * $b;
            echo "El producto es $producto </br>";
            //Apartado 5
            $resta = sqrt($a) - pow($b,3);
            echo "El resultado es $resta </br>";
            //Apartado 6
            if ($b >= $a) {
               $restodi = $b % $a;
               echo "El resultado es $restodi </br>";
            }
            else {
                echo "B debe ser mayor que A </br>";
            }
            //Apartado 7
            $ope1 = (max($a,$b)* 5)/(min($a,$b));
            echo "$ope1 </br>";
            //Apartado 8
            $div1 = (int) $a / $b * 0.66666;
            echo "El entero de la división es $div1 </br>";
            //Apartado 9
            $div2 = (float) $a / $b * 0.66666;
            echo "El resultado de la división es $div2 </br>";
            if ($a >= $b) {
                $difact = $a / gmp_fact($b);
                $redon = round($difact);
                echo "El resultado es $redond </br>";
            } else {
                $difact2 = $b / gmp_fact($a);
                $redon2= round($difact2);
                echo "El resultado es $redond2 </br>";
            }
            //Apartado 10
            $nurand = mt_rand(min($a,$b),max($a,$b));
            echo "El número aleatorio es $nurand </br>";
            //Apartado 11
            $uma = min($a,$b)+max($a,$b);
            echo "La suma es $uma </br>";
        ?>
```

Comment: talves no entra al else

Comment: No es ese el problema, simplemente no me funciona esa parte, no funciona del factroial para abajo

Comment: Tal vez deberías de hacer una pregunta aparte, sobre como instalar `PHP-GMP` en Arch Linux. Creo que entra dentro de la temática del sitio, como `herramientas de software`.

Comment: @ras212 ¿ no te vale hacerlo directamente en PHP, sin extensiones, para números enteros ?

Comment: si, ya lo he solucionado

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Que no te de error puede ser cuestión de cómo tengas configurado el servidor. Si le tienes puesto que no muestre errores, aunque la función de fallo, no verás nada. Prueba a poner esto al principio de tu código para que muestre los errores:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Ahora yo veo el siguiente mensaje de error:

[image: Error al usar gmp_fact]

Ahora, el problema es que estás usando la función `gmp_fact` que es parte de la [clase GMP](http://php.net/manual/en/class.gmp.php) y no tienes activada la extensión que incluye esa clase en PHP. Para ello puedes hacer lo siguiente:

1. Asegúrate de que tienes instalada la extensión GMP para PHP. Puedes ver una [pregunta en StackOverflow en inglés](https://serverfault.com/questions/429585/how-to-install-enable-gmp-math-functions-for-php-on-ubuntu) sobre esto. Resumiendo:

   - Para Linux puedes instalarla haciendo algo como esto si tienes PHP5:

     ```
     apt-get install php5-gmp
     ```

     o así si tienes PHP7:

     ```
     apt-get install php7.0-gmp
     ```
2. Abre php.ini
3. Busca la sección en la que se incluyen las extensiones
4. Busca una fila en la que se añada la extensión GMP

   1. Si existe, descoméntala (quita el `;` del principio)
   2. Si no existe, añádela. En Windows sería algo como esto:

      ```
      extension=php_gmp.dll
      ```

      Y en Linux sería así:

      ```
      extension=php_gmp.do
      ```
5. Reinicia tu servidor para que se tomen los cambios que hiciste en php.ini

Ahora al probar de nuevo y ya funciona sin problemas (tuve que corregir un pequeño error tipográfico - donde ponía `$redond2` y debería ser `$redon2`, igual para `$redond` y `$redon`):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Voy con la 7.1, tu tienes la 5.6? Incluso con error reporting no me muestra nada

Comment: Eso era más una nota que la respuesta, pero es raro. ¿Te funciona lo de añadir la extensión gmp?

Comment: no, no aparece enel php.ini mi sistema operaetivo es arch (manjaro KDE) aunque no debería de afectar no?

Comment: He harreglado las letras que se han colado, pero nada

Comment: @ras212 estás en linux, así que en lugar de ser `extension=php_gmp.dll` sería `extension=php_gmp.so`. Prueba a añadir eso

Comment: He añadido instrucciones con como instalar GMP en Linux, puede ser que no tengas ese paquete instalado en tu servidor

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro, el OP comenta que usa `arch Linux`. No la uso, pero estoy seguro de que usa `pacman` como gestor de paquetes. `apt-get` es para Debian y derivadas. Tal vez sería conveniente una pregunta aparte ?

Comment: @Trauma gracias por el comentario. La verdad es que no sé cómo se haría con `pacman`, buscando rápido en Google encuentro [dos](https://pierre-schmitz.com/php-7-on-arch-linux/) [páginas](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/256338) que podrían ser de ayuda para OP. Pero tienes razón, eso sería más el tema de otra pregunta.

Comment: voy a probarla, muchas gracias por todo